# Laravel Eloquent - bulk update with whereIn array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, where-in

I'm working on a project where I need to update many rows at once per coin Id.

in order to update all coins values, Im getting them all from the API, so for example I have back:

```
    $coinsList= [[id="bitcoin", symbol="btc", name="Bintcoin"],[id="etherium", symbol="eth", name="Etherium"]];
```

and the database table columns is the following:

```
**| id | coin_id | symbol | name |**
```

now, I want to **update** all values to the database, according to the **id** only, so this is what I did:

```
    // first get ids from my table
    $exist_ids = Coinlist::all('coin_id')->pluck('coin_id')->toArray();
    
    //get all ids to update (to ignore other ids):
    $updatable_ids = array_values(array_intersect($exist_ids, $allCoinIds));//result for example is: array("bitcoin","etherium");
    
//and now, update the database:
    Coinlist::whereIn('coin_id', $updatable_ids)
                ->update([
                    'symbol' => $coinsList[$key]['symbol'],
                    'name' => $coinsList[$key]['name'],
                    'updated_at' => now()
                ]);
```

the problem is, I don't have the "$key" in order to update the right row, what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: WhereIn returns a collection of objects. If you use update after whereIn laravel try to update all fields of selected collections with the same value. You can not assign a different value to the individual for each item. Try using for or foreach instead.

Comment: Thank you @YasinBARAN, it means, I will have to update in the DB each item individually? (it's around 13K items every minute) isn't it a bad practice?

Comment: Yes, it is bad practice. I can propose you use DB queries instead of Eloquent to make updates faster or you can check packages like "iksaku/laravel-mass-update".

Comment: Thank you @YasinBARAN -> this library is way faster than the one I have today (mavinoo/laravelBatch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good way to solve it:
in the beginning, I used this library: https://github.com/mavinoo/laravelBatch
to update many dynamic rows, but it was really slow, then thanks to Yasin, I moved to: https://github.com/iksaku/laravel-mass-update and now it works way better.

the implementation is simple, add a simple code to the Model class, then add:

```
User::massUpdate(
    values: [
        ['username' => 'iksaku', 'name' => 'Jorge González'],
        ['username' => 'gm_mtz', 'name' => 'Gladys Martínez'],
    ],
    uniqueBy: 'username'
);
```

while uniqueBy is the key for the row, and add other columns values to change them dynamically.